# Cannot download file after redirect from asp file to aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I have asp classic file, which redirects to aspx file that downloads excel files.

When the asp redirect to the aspx file, nothing is happening.

But if i get the link to the aspx and open it in new tab, everything works fine :

ASP Code :

```
Dim NodeIDsCSV : NodeIDsCSV = ""
Dim NodeIDsCSV = Init_PrepareParams()


Dim sharedSecret : sharedSecret = ""
Dim identityAlias : identityAlias = ""

sharedSecret = GetSharedSecret()

identityAlias = GetIdentityAlias()


Response.Redirect "/testCMS/testCMSv2.aspx?NodeIDsCSV=" & NodeIDsCSV & "&SS=" & sharedSecret & "&IdentityAlias=" & identityAlias
```

ASPX Code :

```
string[] nodes = NodeIDsCSV.Split(',');
   

    
    //Create a stream for the file
    Stream stream = null;

    //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
    int bytesToRead = 100000;

    // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
    var fileName = "test.xlsx";
    // The number of bytes read
    try
    {
        //Create a WebRequest to get the file
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            
        HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("--link--to--service--which-returns-the-file");
        fileReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        //Create a response for this request
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse) fileReq.GetResponse();

        if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

        //Get the Stream returned from the response
        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

        // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
        var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        //resp.ClearHeaders();
        //Indicate the type of data being sent
        resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        //Name the file 
        resp.Clear();
        //resp.Buffer = false;
        //resp.BufferOutput = false;
        
        //Apparently this line helps with old version of IE that like to cache stuff no matter how much you tell them!
        resp.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(fileName + "----fileName----");
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        
        int length;


        do
        {
            // Verify that the client is connected.
            
            if (resp.IsClientConnected)
            {
            
                // Read data into the buffer.
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                // and write it out to the response's output stream
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
    
                // Flush the data
                //resp.Flush();
                
                //Clear the buffer
                buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                
            }
            else
            {
                // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                length = -1;
            }
        } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
        
    }
```

What could be my problem ? And can you suggest me some different solution to the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using your browser developer tools to ensure that the classic ASP page is redirecting as expected and how the ASPX page is responding?

Comment: Yes @JackA. i tried, the aspx returns the xml of the file, but after the redirect, the file is not downloaded. But, when i get directly the link to the browser and skip the redirection, the file is downloaded successfully.

Comment: Why set the response to `application/octet-stream` if you know you're downloading an Excel file? Find it hard to believe you don't get any errors and are not able to determine anything from the dev tools network tab, do you have "preserve log" tick so requests are persisted in the network tab?